# Why is Wingpanel-Slim not working in Elementary Luna after installing and activating it?

Tags: elementary-os, panel

~[via](https://plus.google.com/105566616654124192478/posts/TzEwV6fnGro) a question that says:

*I am using wingpanel-slim, but it reverts back to wingpanel after each logout, even though wingpanel-slim is still shown as activated in Tweaks. Any ideas how I can stop this happening?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug with the Elementary Tweaks. After activating Wingpanel Slim,  and going to Cerbere option, both entries are there

[image]

Delete 'Wingpanel'

[image]